# Run Shell script file from Apache web server

Tags: php, html, apache2

I am running an Apache 2 webserver. I would like to have a button which, when pressed, activates a shell script.
I have found similar questions which have an answer to use a php file.

The html file is like this:

```
<form action="testexec.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Open Script">
</form>
```

And the PHP file is like this:

```
<?php
shell_exec("./test.sh");
?>
```

However, when I click the button on the html page, it brings up the php page but nothing runs. If I do: php testexec.php in the terminal everything runs fine.

Is there any way to fix this? 
Thanks in advance

Edit: I tried replacing the php script to just exec instead of shell_exec but it still doesn't work. I also tried replacing './test.sh' with a python script command 'python pythonscript.py' but the python script wouldn't run either apart from when I ran it from the terminal.
Is it something to do with Apache?

Comment: `php testexec.php` and `test.sh` are two totally different scripts. Can you check the permissions on `test.sh` ?

Comment: I did chmod 7777 on test.sh

Comment: If you're using PHP < 5.3 it might be that [safe mode](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.sect.safe-mode.php) is enabled, [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.functions.php) is one of the functions disabled in this mode. As well as running ``chmod`` on test.sh you will also need to ``chmod +x testexec.php`` to allow the php script to execute an external script.

Comment: Maybe also there a path issuer, try use absolute path to the script instead the relative one

Comment: My Apache server is on a raspberry pi and the aim of the shell script was to run a python script which would light an led and the shell script did some other commands such as touch. I realised that touch was working and a new file was being created but the LED wasn't lighting because if the fact that only root can do this. A Google search brought me to this:http://forums.connectedly.com/raspberry-pi-f179/how-controlling-gpio-pins-via-internet-2884/?amp Anyway thanks for your help everyone